# How works multiplication just after incrementation (i++ * 2) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, increment, multiplication

Please read whole topic, before post answer. No answer found to this question in post: ++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript

```
var i = 1;
i = i++ * 2; // i = 2, .. why not 4 ?
```

interpreter does the multiply (1*2), but where is the increment ( i++ )?

```
var i = 1;
i = ++1 * 2; // i = 4
```

I'm understand, that the i++ does the increment after the statement, ++i does it before the statement, but in this example: i = i++ * 2 // (1*2), how the interpreter works?, where is the increment of i in this case? maybe i = (1*2)+1 )), or i = (1*2) and no more i exist, and nothing to increment??

### HOW ?

P.S. I think, it is a wrong question, but as Brooks Hanes said(in comment), this is a learning example.

Comment: i++ does the increment after the statement, ++i does it before the statement

Comment: It's no just JavaScript, increment operator works in many (most if not all) languages like this

Comment: This question is a good example of writing code in such a way that is not instantly understandable. I know this is probably a learning example, but many, many mistakes have been made from trying to save a line of computation.

Comment: Does it really even matter: i = (i + 1) *2; seems just as easy.

Comment: But you are assigning the whole thing to i. So I will get updated correctly in the end.  Now I could see if you wanted to j = ++i * 2;

Comment: I think, it is a wrong question.. sorry.

As  Brooks Hanes said, this is a learning example. I'm understand, that the i++ does the increment after the statement, ++i does it before the statement, but in example: i = i++ * 2 // (1*2), how the interpreter works?, where is the increment of i in this case? 
maybe i = (1*2)+1 )), or i = (1*2) and no more i exist, and nothing to increment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting little problem, a simple experiment shows what is happening. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smylydon/3A2Ut/)

```
var i = 3; p = i++ *2; console.log(i, p);
```

The 2 is multiplied by i (3) the result (6) is placed in p. Then a copy of the original value of i (3) is incremented and placed back in i. This behaviour is logically consistent with the following:

```
var i = 3; var p = 0; function adder(x) { p = x + 2; }; adder(i++); console.log(i, p);
```

This makes a strange kind of sense because the post increment is supposed to happen after the statement.

Comment: Michael Godden  -Thankyou! this is the right answer, that i am waiting for.

Answer (score 10):

i++ means: read the value of variable i, then increase variable i

++i means: increase variable i, then read the value of variable i

Comment: ++i means: read the value of variable i, increase variable i and then read the value of variable i

Comment: i++ means: read the value of variable i, then increase variable i and then read the value of variable i

Comment: @vivoconunxino those sound exactly the same to me as you have described.